# Clone xlsx sheet within same workbook in SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I am working on SSIS package where i have to clone xlsx sheet within same workbook. Is there any way to do so without using interop dll.

Can we achieve this by using OLEDB connections?

Comment: See following : https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/9014/read-write-excel-file-with-oledb-in-c-without-interop

Comment: @jdweng  in mentioned post it's only reading and writing from/to xlsx using OLEDB. But my requirement is to copy all data from Sheet1 with all formating and formulas into Sheet2. How can i accomplish this copy task.

Comment: You can't without using the Interop.  The excel interface is proprietary so you can only format using the Interop.